# FOSUser + FOSRest - Update User

Tags: rest, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I'm using Fosuser and Fosrest for a webservice.
I created GetUser to get List user and the registration to register an user and it work perfectly !
But, now I try to make the update user but i got a problem !

I copy the function from Fosuser controller

In My controller :

```
public function updatePostAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

it doesn't work ! anyone can help me ?

When i try to post :

```
{
    "fos_user_profile_form": {
        "username":"jacky"
    }
}
```

it returns : https://gist.github.com/gaticho/34ae4fff5492fdecd48f

The database doesn't change :-(

My User entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateDeleted;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}`
```

Thanks !

Comment: You need to post the exception log or something, are the action executed?, where fail?

Comment: whats the error? what debugging have you done so far and what were the results?

Comment: i try to post : {
"fos_user_profile_form":{
"username":"jacky"
}
} but it cannot update the user in the database

Comment: Please share your error in your question ...

Comment: it returns : https://gist.github.com/gaticho/34ae4fff5492fdecd48f